# Count Comments for Facebook Posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fbml

i have a bunch of facebook post's,
Any ideas how to get the **one with the most comments** as fast as possible?

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FQL:

```
select post_id, comments.count from stream where post_id in("post_id1", ... , "post_idX") order by comments.count desc limit 1
```

Comment: That was my first idea as well. Do you think this will work with 10.000? 50.000? posts as well?

Comment: @fabian might not work. Facebook often doesn't like numbers over 5,000, in this case you would need to manually split your big list to chunks of 5k.